# 403: Request had insufficient authentication scopes - gcloud container clusters get-credentials

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, roles, gcloud, gitlab-ci-runner

I need to connect to GKE kubernetes cluster from gitlab runner, but I don't want to use AutoDevops feature, I would like to setup all of those things on my own. So, basically I would like to install gcloud sdk on a gitlab runner, then set gcloud account to my service account, authorize with the generated key and finally perform "gcloud container clusters get-credentials ..." command to get a valid kubernetes config - to be able to interact with kubernetes cluster.

Interesting fact is, that I tried to perform the entire procedure on my local machine using docker with the same image - and it works here! I does not work only on gitlab runner. The only difference is that gitlab runner is running not with docker executor but on kubernetes one (on the same k8s I want to interact with).

So the working case is:

```
$ winpty docker run -it --entrypoint=sh lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest
# apk add python
# wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
# tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-# # reporting=false --path-update=true > /dev/null
# PATH="google-cloud-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
# gcloud config set account <my-service-account>
# gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json --project=<my_project>
# gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster1 --zone europe-west2-b --project <my_project>
# kubectl get all
```

but when I try do do the same with gitlab runner:
gitlab-ci-yml:

```
deployment_be:
  image: lachlanevenson/k8s-kubectl:latest
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - kubernetes
  before_script:
    - apk add python
  script:
    # Download and install Google Cloud SDK
    - wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz
    - tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false --path-update=true
    - PATH="google-cloud-sdk/bin:${PATH}"
    # Authorize with service account and fetch k8s config file
    - gcloud config set account <my_service_account>
    - gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json --project=<my_project>
    - gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster1 --zone europe-west2-b --project <my_project>
    # Interact with kubectl
    - kubectl get all
```

I get the following error:

```
$ gcloud config set account <my_service_account>
Updated property [core/account].
$ gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=key.json --project=<my_project>
Activated service account credentials for: [<my_service_account>]
$ gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster1 --zone europe-west2-b --project <my_project>
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) ResponseError: code=403, message=Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

I tried to set all possible roles for this service account, including: Compute Administrator,
Kubernetes Engine Administrator,
Kubernetes Engine Clusters Administrator,
Container Administrator,
Editor,
Owner

Why this service account works fine on isolated docker image and on the same image launched over kubernetes cluster it fails ?

Comment: Indeed curious. Can you try adding `--log-http` to the `get-credentials` to see whether we can get more detail from the call?

Comment: and|or check whether `~/.kube/config` was updated.

Comment: http log: https://pastebin.com/6YUmwgPq , unfortunately I'm not able to check if ~/.kube/config is updated (I guess it's not), because just after get-credentials command I'm getting error and container stops.

Comment: Your pastebin (thanks) confirms that `https://container.googleapis.com/v1/` is throwing the 403. Please (continue) to not paste any tokens here but, if you are presented with the bearer token in those logs, you may wish to try querying the token to confirm its scope: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=${YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN}`.

Comment: Hmmm.... actually this is curious, the logs include `scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"` which is the superuser of scopes and grants full access. This must refer to your account's existing scopes. So that's something of a red-herring.

Comment: I'm going to try to repro this by using your container image.

Comment: Regrettably, I'm out of ideas. I am able to successfully run the commands (as you do) locally. I wondered whether Gitlab uses docker-in-docker and that was the issue. But, I tried that too and it works. I'm unable (don't have) to repro using Gitlab. Given that this works in Docker, I'm inclined to believe there's something different when Gitlab runs this and encourage you to consider asking the Gitlab folks for guidance.

Comment: One other "perhaps?" while walking my dog, whether gitlab runs the container as non-root and that makes a difference? Clutching at straws

Comment: Ok, I resolved my problem, but actually It's still not clear for me why it hasn't worked before... So - I created a new VM on gcloud, with full access to API, and I launched gitlab runner on the new machine - and it works fine here. Anyway, thanks a lot for help, and thinking about my problem even during walking a dog :)  Cheers!